# Why does scipy.optimize rely so heavily on start values?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize` to do some simple optimization problems, but I find that I can only find the solution with a very limited range of start values. Here is a minimum replicable example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.optimize import minimize

p = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
neg_likelihood = lambda p: -1 * st.binom.pmf(6, n=9, p=p)
minimize(neg_likelihood, 0.3)
```

The shape of the `neg_likelihood` function is like the following picture, so the right answer should be around `0.65`:

[image]

Trying out different start values, I found that the right solution can be found only when the start value of `p` is between `0.1` and `0.4`. The minimization algorithm seems highly unstable.

I tried several different minimization algorithms (BFGS, Powell, etc.), they have yield similar results, so I guess the problem must be mine, not the algorithms'.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard numerical optimization routines use the function value (the value you want to optimize) and the gradient (roughly landscape information of your function).

You only provided the function. Therefore optimization routines have to approximate the gradient. Whenever you can calculate the gradient, add this source of information and do not rely on approximations.

Here I do the math by hand and do not use the functions in stats. log transformation makes calculating the gradient easier.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b

# do the math by hand, it's quite simple in this case
def target_fun(p, k, n):
    f = - k* np.log(p) - (n-k)*np.log(1-p)
    g =  - k/p + (n-k) / (1-p)
    return f, g

f = lambda p: target_fun(p, k=6, n=9)
epsilon = 1e-9
fmin_l_bfgs_b(f, 0.999, bounds=[(epsilon,1-epsilon)])
```

When you add gradient information, the optimization routine successfully finds the optimum for arbitrary start values.

Comment: Thanks! I read some documentation that having the gradients can speed up the optimization, but never knew without it I can get into trouble. What if in some circumstances the gradients are hard to get? In this example simply adding the bounds will solve the problem.

Comment: Actually a good question. I am not so sure anymore if there are low dimensional cases in which the gradient information is crucial and the approximations will not work. In this case I guess the log transform (makeing the plateau at the ends steep) and the bounds are the most important factors.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function is undefined (returns nan) for `x` outside [0,1], which the optimizers do not like.

You can try specifying `bounds=[(0,1)]` option to inform the optimizers about this --- the nan returns however cause problems for the gradient approximation at the endpoints.

Since you only have one variable, you can use special optimizers for 1D problems, which access only values within bounds:

```
print minimize_scalar(neg_likelihood, bracket=(0, 0.5, 1))
```